# Request property is missing in NetCore controllerBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm migrating a WebApi to NetCore 2.2, but in netCore 2.2 doesn't exist propety Request and i need it in the fallowing code:

```
private HttpResponseMessage GetImsResponse(ImsRequest req)
{
    try
    {
        var response = service.Process(req);

        if (response is IErrorResponse)
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ((IErrorResponse)response).Message);

        if (response != null)
            if (response.HasImage())
            {
                var httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
                httpResponse.Content = new StreamContent((Stream)response.GetImage());
                httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                return httpResponse;
                //Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, response.Message);
            }
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GetObjectForRepresentInJson());
    }
}
```

ImsRequest is a class implemented by me. And also need it in:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Index()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() => GetImsResponse(Request));
}
```

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage` is no longer part of the Controller in that version.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2 I'll answer how you can add it to your controller

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing was *never* a good way to do it. Just return actual result types from your private method. In Core:

```
private IActionResult GetImsResponse(ImsRequest req)
{
    var response = service.Process(req);

    if (response is IErrorResponse)
        return BadRequest(((IErrorResponse)response).Message);

    if (response != null)
    {
        if (response.HasImage())
        {
            return File(response.GetImage(), "image/png");
        }

        return Ok(response.GetObjectForRepresentInJson());
    }

    return // return something when response is null
}
```

Then:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionReslt Index()
{
    return GetImsResponse(Request);
}
```

There's nothing async happening here, so using `Task.Factory.StartNew` is pointless, especially since you're awaiting it, and would *have* to await it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved, in this case i can change:

```
                        return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response.GetObjectForRepresentInJson());
```

TO:

```
var httpRespose = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        httpRespose.Content = new StringContent("No se pudo obtener un protocolo que resolviera el pedido");
        return httpRespose;
```